# Can I have a logical replication between 2 databases in the same postgres server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, postgresql-11

I am creating a logical replication between to databases of two different applications. However at development environment my databases stays at the same postgres docker container.

My application uses rails, and so I created a migration to create the subscription from the publisher. But when I run it, it just holds forever. If I create another container and separates the databases the subscription goes swell.

Is there anyway I can do it to run at the same container?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looks like you have run into this caveat spelled out in [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-createsubscription.html), and need to follow the two-step procedure described there:

> Creating a subscription that connects to the same database cluster
>   (for example, to replicate between databases in the same cluster or to
>   replicate within the same database) will only succeed if the
>   replication slot is not created as part of the same command.
>   Otherwise, the CREATE SUBSCRIPTION call will hang. To make this work,
>   create the replication slot separately (using the function
>   pg_create_logical_replication_slot with the plugin name pgoutput) and
>   create the subscription using the parameter create_slot = false.